# Exchange 2016 ECP failing - 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: windows, iis, exchange, exchange-2016, microsoft

My Exchange server is really suffering at the moment. I do not know what has happened but when I connect /ECP I get 503 errors. I can view the login page successfully, but after a successful login all I see is a blank page.

/OWA is stable and working correctly.

I have already verified IIS is using the correct SSL binding certificates for the default and Exchange backend sites (we have our own 3rd party SSL that is NOT expired - it was working fine up until yesterday). Even if I switch to the Exchange certificate the same issue occurs.

The only change that may could have impacted this imo is that, I added a group of IP addresses into ISS > Default Web Site > ECP. I then set up a feature setting to Deny > Abort everyone else. Stupid me applied the same settings to ISS > Exchange Back End > ECP. I later read you shouldn't edit this section. Could this be why it's no longer working?

This is my virtual directory data:

```
Get-EcpVirtualDirectory "mx03\ecp (Default Web Site)"|select-object InternalUrl, ExternalUrl, B
asicAuthentication,WindowsAuthentication,DigestAuthentication, FormsAuthentication


InternalUrl           : https://<localdomain>/ecp
ExternalUrl           : https://<publicdomain>/ecp
BasicAuthentication   : True
WindowsAuthentication : False
DigestAuthentication  : False
FormsAuthentication   : True
```

These are some logs from IIS:

```
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_OUT_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_OUT_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_OUT_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_OUT_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_OUT_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - - 2 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
81 HTTP/1.1 RPC_IN_DATA /rpc/rpcproxy.dll?<localdomain>:6001 - 503 2 N/A MSExchangeRpcProxyAppPool
443 HTTP/1.1 GET /ecp - 503 1 N/A MSExchangeECPAppPool
```

If anyone can provide some additional troubleshooting or assistance I'd truly be grateful. I feel like I have been banging my head against a wall these past few days, trying to figure this out and the exhaustion is eating away at me.

KR,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

What's your Exchange 2016 CU version?

Like you said above,I'm afraid the issue was casuld by the changes you made in IIS. Could you try restoring the changes to IIS to before then run iisreset and verify the result again.

In addition, are you going to limit the access to Exchange admin center? If so, try the steps introduced in the official document here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/disable-exchange-admin-center-access?view=exchserver-2016